# Calculating if a number is even or odd in scheme using tail recursion

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

I'm using the following functions in scheme48 to calculate if a number is even or odd.

```
(define (odds? x)
    (if (= x 0) #f
        ((evens? (- x 1))
        )))

(define (evens? x)
    (if (= x 0) #t
        ((odds? (- x 1))
        )))
```

However upon doing so I recieve the following error:

> Error: attempt to call a non-procedure
>          (#t)

I would appreciate it if someone could explain what exactly this error means, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of erroneous `()` surrounding the last function call, and the formatting can be improved. Remember, in Scheme a pair of `()` means "function application" (that explains the error message `attempt to call a non-procedure`), so you have to be careful where you put them. Try this instead:

```
(define (odds? x)
    (if (= x 0)
        #f
        (evens? (- x 1))))

(define (evens? x)
    (if (= x 0)
        #t
        (odds? (- x 1))))
```

Comment: Thank you Oscar, it seems I made a careless mistake.

Comment: @InfoSecNoob don't worry, use your IDE or text editor to help with this kind of problem, after a bit of practice the parentheses won't cause any trouble :)